# What determines Cosmog's evolution?

Tags: pokemon

Cosmog ("Get in the bag, Nebby!")  can evolve into either Lunala or Solgaleo. In terms of game mechanics, obviously, what Cosmog evolves into depends on which game you purchase.

However, *in-universe*, what determines which of the two Legendaries Cosmog evolves into? Things like the King's Rock and affection exist in-universe, but game versions probably don't. How does Cosmog evolve? Or is it random?

Comment: Are different games same canon?

Comment: @Discovery - It's all a sort of mish-mosh. But you need both a Lunala and a Solgaleo to produce a Cosmog, and they undoubtedly will both show up in the anime....

Comment: Pure supposition, but if it grows with light, could it not evolve to suit whichever form of light it's been exposed to (e.g. mostly sunlight / mostly moonlight)?